# How can get the HTML of an anchor selected by its text string?

Tags: jquery, html, text, hyperlink, href

Is there a way to get code behind a content in jQuery, like `<a href="http://www.example.com" class="link">Text</a>`

So i need something like: `if ($(".link").text() == "Text"){alert("<a href="http://www.example.com" class="link">Text</a>");}`

The thing is that i need to get the text from `alert();` from page, and maybe some code before.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to capture something from an alert?

Comment: I want to get whole link html code, using his content as an identificator. I need to get: <a href="http://example.com">Text</a> as an output using Text as identificator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this link:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="link">Text</a>
```

... you can get its HTML like so:

```
var myLink = $('a:contains("Text")')[0].outerHTML;
```

... and then do with it what you will.

```
alert(myLink);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fxyvc1qe/)

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405571/1264804)

---

Here's how you'd get the anchor's parent element as well:

```
var myLink = $('a:contains("Text")').parent()[0].outerHTML;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fxyvc1qe/3/)

---

Aaaaaaand, to add a class to the outer element, you could do this:

```
var myLink = $('a:contains("Text")').parent();

$(myLink).addClass('my-class');

var myLinkHtml = $(myLink)[0].outerHTML;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fxyvc1qe/4/)

Comment: This is pretty close to what i need, but is there a way to get more code, like <div class="div"><a href="http://www.example.com" class="link">Text</a></div>

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: So you also want the parent element? Or you want to add an element to the link HTML?

Comment: Something like that, can i have an example if possible of how to get one or more parrents of a link? So its not possible to get what code i want?

Comment: Its like, i need a parent div of a link, and i need to add a class to that div.

Comment: Your question keeps changing. Take the time to edit your original question to make it clear and complete.

Comment: Than you sir, this is what i really needed! Now how can i add a class to the parent element?

Comment: You are a jquery god :D Thank you very much, you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
if($('.link:contains("Text")')){
  alert("Text");
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for the HTML for the link, not its text value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a link like this:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
```

You can do

```
if ($(".link").html()=="Text") {
    alert("Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get the html for the element with an id of `my-link`:**

`$("#my-link")[0].outerHTML`

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/57en1v9s/

**Get the html for the element with the text of `sample text`:**

`$("a:contains('sample text')")[0].outerHTML`

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/z3ymh84c/

Comment: I don't need to get the value of the href attribute, i need to get whole HTML code for that like (<a href="http://example.com">Text</a>)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I updated my answer and my examples to reflect what you said.

Comment: Yes, thats it, now i can get the code and it's parent, is there a way to add a class to his parent?